# boost/geometry replacement in Java/for the JVM (Destructable Box2D terrain)

Tags: c++, java, box2d, geometry

I'd like to reimplement https://github.com/seemk/DestructibleBox2D in Java. The main problem is finding an adequate replacement for the boost/geometry library.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not write your own geometry library?

Comment: @Honeybunch Because I don't want to re-implement the wheel and it seems kind of tedious. I've already implemented my own maths-library for a 3D game, so there is not really anything to gain.

Comment: Have you seen the Java Topology Suite? http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm